# Solrj query Response

Tags: solrj, solr4, java-6

Hi I a trying fetch the query result from apache solr.

Using Solrj jar I am fetching the query result with the help of QueryResponse class but I am getting the following errror.

Exception message:

Error executing query

Exception trace:

```
at   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:100)
at   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:301)
at   com.adastra.candidate.search.solr.action.SolrSearchAction.aaaExecute(SolrSearchAction.java:48)
at   com.adastra.base.action.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:181)
at   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:425)
at   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:228)
at   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
at   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
at   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
at   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
at   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can u please suggest me, where I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you post the code?Where is the caused by in the exception trace?can you post the full exception ?

Comment: The above one is full exception trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Perikli, 
but it got sorted out.

The code is as follows:

```
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

QueryResponse qResponse = solrServer.query(queryForFecthing);
```

Actually Exception got while creating object of `QueryResponse` i.e. `qResponse` and I thought it because of query which I am passing as a parameter( i.e. as per above is '**queryForFecthing**').

But it was wrong assumption and actually it was because of invalid url passed
during creation of object for `SolrServer` ( i.e **solrServer** )

Comment: Suggestion : Kindly add your core or collection name along with the URL. Say for example collection name be collection1, then URL should be http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1